# Error bars stacked in a wrong position on a bar plot

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a nice barplot with error bars for standard deviation also depsite my multiple trials the error bars are stacked in the wrong position.

Here are my data:

```
Gas   Days       Mean          SD
1   H2  Day 1  0.2400000  0.21000000
2   O2  Day 1  0.6366667  0.19604421
3   N2  Day 1 77.2900000 13.75532533
4  CO2  Day 1 16.4916667 10.39674989
5  CH4  Day 1  5.3416667  3.83135202
6   H2  Day 2  0.2333333  0.20428738
7   O2  Day 2  0.4383333  0.16002604
8   N2  Day 2 44.2500000 14.08799844
9  CO2  Day 2 42.7866667 11.39435972
10 CH4  Day 2 12.2916667  4.78424585
11  H2  Day 3  0.2733333  0.23671361
12  O2  Day 3  0.3250000  0.10688779
13  N2  Day 3 27.7216667 15.22521456
14 CO2  Day 3 56.4416667 12.16887252
15 CH4  Day 3 15.2383333  6.94239932
16  H2  Day 4  1.4466667  1.25766980
17  O2  Day 4  0.3033333  0.05773503
18  N2  Day 4 16.2316667  6.95301433
19 CO2  Day 4 65.2433333  8.22831899
20 CH4  Day 4 16.7750000  8.38279637
21  H2  Day 5  1.8566667  2.00335552
22  O2  Day 5  0.2616667  0.09776673
23  N2  Day 5 15.6350000  8.93383596
24 CO2  Day 5 63.6966667  9.59953688
25 CH4  Day 5 18.5500000  9.69971262
26  H2  Day 6  1.6716667  1.78400065
27  O2  Day 6  0.2350000  0.06500000
28  N2  Day 6 13.4150000  7.12756445
29 CO2  Day 6 65.6600000 10.06767476
30 CH4  Day 6 19.0183333  9.89617392
31  H2  Day 7  1.1200000  1.10054532
32  O2  Day 7  0.4600000  0.22754121
33  N2  Day 7 16.3750000  9.19611467
34 CO2  Day 7 61.3800000 10.13565859
35 CH4  Day 7 20.6650000  7.79423986
36  H2  Day 8  0.6900000  0.73912110
37  O2  Day 8  1.5516667  1.43711807
38  N2  Day 8 22.7566667 10.31327462
39 CO2  Day 8 55.0300000  8.11610898
40 CH4  Day 8 19.9716667  8.01568826
41  H2  Day 9  0.4433333  0.46651188
42  O2  Day 9  2.0066667  0.74272023
43  N2  Day 9 27.3016667  2.89531662
44 CO2  Day 9 53.0733333  9.65077760
45 CH4  Day 9 17.1750000  9.12358071
46  H2 Day 10  2.3750000  2.17672346
47  O2 Day 10  0.4550000  0.19487175
48  N2 Day 10 18.9450000  5.68961554
49 CO2 Day 10 61.8850000  6.92923697
50 CH4 Day 10 16.3400000  6.25216562
51  H2 Day 11  1.2783333  1.12823239
52  O2 Day 11  0.2733333  0.10539608
53  N2 Day 11 16.8333333  7.48480516
54 CO2 Day 11 62.9100000  9.53468536
55 CH4 Day 11 18.7050000  3.37377015
56  H2 Day 12  0.7133333  0.67419087
57  O2 Day 12  0.3100000  0.14933185
58  N2 Day 12 11.5800000  5.37798289
59 CO2 Day 12 70.0883333 10.58705145
60 CH4 Day 12 17.3083333  4.82756236
61  H2 Day 13  0.7100000  0.62217361
62  O2 Day 13  0.3400000  0.19467922
63  N2 Day 13 12.8033333  7.17844226
64 CO2 Day 13 68.0550000 11.30319756
65 CH4 Day 13 18.0916667  3.40131715
66  H2 Day 14  0.6566667  0.56888780
67  O2 Day 14  0.3150000  0.14773287
68  N2 Day 14 12.5216667  4.52830082
69 CO2 Day 14 68.1916667  8.50706520
70 CH4 Day 14 18.3150000  3.64874293
71  H2 Day 15  1.5716667  1.66415394
72  O2 Day 15  0.2833333  0.09237604
73  N2 Day 15 11.6466667  4.91058635
74 CO2 Day 15 67.5316667  7.44128405
75 CH4 Day 15 18.9666667  1.10336229
```

And here is my ggplot statement:

```
pg2 <- ggplot(data = gas2, aes(x=Days, y= Mean, fill=Gas)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",
                                                               position="stack", color = "black")
+ theme_bw() + scale_fill_manual(values = gas_color) + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 12),legend.text = element_text(size= 12),axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",size =12), axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12))+ scale_x_discrete(limit = c("Day 1","Day 2","Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7","Day 8", "Day 9","Day 10", "Day 11", "Day 12", "Day 13","Day 14","Day 15"))

plot <- pg2 + geom_errorbar(data = gas2, aes(ymax=Mean+SD, ymin=Mean-SD),stat = 'identity', position = 'identity', width=.2, color = "white")

plot(plot)
```

And here is the graph I got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auDPo.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your error bars are in the "wrong" place, because you're stacking your bars. If you change the `position` argument from `stack` to `dodge`, your error bars will be in correct place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for me. It produces one graph with the wrong colors and the errors bars are still "in the middle of the graph".